# Specifying desktop text for Apple iPhone apple touch icon HTML attribute

Tags: iphone, html

The HTML tag : 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/customIcon.png"/>

seems to picks up the text it will use from the first 12 characters of the HTML tag:

<title>123456789012...</title>

when you select the 'Add to Home' option in the Safari browser. However only the first 9 character are displayed in the iPhone's desktop. If more than 9 are in the text dialog box, the result is a '...' name on the desktop of the iPhone. The <title> tag often has more than 9 or 12 characters to name the web page.

Is there a way to keep the web page's <title> attribute intact and long while specifying a 9 character name of the desktop icon on the iPhone?

I have tried the:
title="12345689" attribute in the <link rel> attribute with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

You can't increase the number of characters shown under the icon but you can get it to default to something other than whats in the `<title>` of the page with this meta tag.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="New Title">
```

I think this may only have support from iOS 6 up though.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way you can lengthen the title on the homescreen. However, native iOS Apps cannot do this either if it's any consolation.